# Expression is not a method

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hello Coders Im trying to code a Anti virus and the following problem was here!

Im trying to add MsgBoxStyle.YesNo and will the problem in this...

So im trying to add a Question for delete file or no with MsgBox.

My code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If My.Settings.ifTmpR = True Then
        For Each aF In Directory.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp)
            Try
                MsgBoxStyle.YesNo()
                MsgBox("Biztosan törli: " + aF)
                IO.File.Delete(aF)
                MsgBox("Temp kiürítése: " + aF)
                MsgBox(aF + "kitötrölve")
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Next
    End If
    If My.Settings.ifTmpR = False Then
        Try
            MsgBox("Kérlek kapcsold be a TEMP Queryt!")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.ifTmpR = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton2.Checked = False Then
        My.Settings.ifTmpR = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And what the problem?

Help?

Comment: Use [MessageBox.Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx), MsgBox is a compatibility leftover with VB6.

Comment: Are you asking us what the problem is?  It almost sounds like you're asking us what your question is/

Comment: get rid of those awful empty Try/Catch blocks so when there is an error you hear about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're coding an Anti-Virus application but you seem to have no basic knowledge about how to use methods and parameters.

You are supposed to include `MsgBoxStyle.YesNo` as one of the parameters to the `MsgBox()` method. You cannot call it like you do since it's simply an Integer value.

As Steve suggested you should use `MessageBox.Show()` instead, due to that `MsgBox` only exists for backwards compability.

The first parameter is the message you want it to show, and the second parameter is what title the window should have. They're just plain strings.

The third parameter however is the one you pass to tell the method what buttons to include in the `MessageBox`, and it should be passed like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("I am a message", "I am a title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

This will show a message box with the buttons "Yes" and "No" inside it.

Now to get use out of this you should put your `MessageBox` in an If-statement, otherwise the application won't care if you press either Yes or No.

```
If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this file?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    'Delete code here.
End If
```

There. Now I suggest that you would have started with something like a "Hello World"-application instead of an Anti-Virus application, as Anti-Virus **is pretty much harder than just showing a simple MessageBox.**